# Package/ class option for swapping text and image in header

Tags: macros, conditionals, documentclass-writing, options

I have a written a `.cls` file which has a command `\makecvheader` that makes a header that looks something like this:

[image]

I have written some class options, and would like to add another one: an option to display the image on the left and the text on the right (with raggedleft), named `photoleft`.

Due to the (current) definition of `\makecvheader`, I can't seem to figure out a way to make this option do what it is supposed to do nor how to make it compatible with the other options.

`photoleft` needs to behave well with the other already existing package options:

- `nophoto` (together with `photoleft`: text on right side, no photo)
- `nophotocenter` (incompatible with `photoleft`)
- `normalphoto` (together with `photoleft`: rectangular photo on the left side, text on the right side)

Due to the use of the `minipage` environment and `ifdef`, I'm stuck. The result I get is:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

% No photo:
\newif\if@nophoto
\DeclareOption{nophoto}{\@nophototrue}
% No photo, centered text:
\newif\if@nophotocentered
\DeclareOption{nophotocenter}{\@nophotocenteredtrue \@nophototrue}
% Photo on the left side, text on the right:
\newif\if@photoleft
\DeclareOption{photoleft}{\@photolefttrue}
% Rectangular photo:
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{geometry}          
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}       
\RequirePackage{xcolor}            
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}   
\RequirePackage{graphicx}        
\RequirePackage{dashrule}      
\RequirePackage{hyperref}         
\RequirePackage{tabularray}         
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}    
\geometry{%
        left=23mm,
        right=23mm, 
        bindingoffset=0mm, 
        top=20mm,
        bottom=20mm
    }

\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\personalinfo}[1]{\def\@personalinfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}

\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \if@nophoto
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}
    \else
        \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em\relax}}{}%
    \fi
    \if@nophotocentered
        \centering
    \fi
    \if@photoleft
        \raggedleft
    \fi
    {\Huge\bfseries\@name\par}
    \medskip
    {\large\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\footnotesize\@personalinfo\par}
    \ifdef{\@photodiameter}{%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \if@nophoto
        % Don't include photo
    \else
        \begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter}
        \if@normalphoto
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\@photo}
        \else
          \tikz\path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];
        \fi%
        \end{minipage}\par}{}%
    \fi%
  \endgroup\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \noindent\linia \medskip
}%


\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[photoleft]{mypackage}

\name{Firstname Lastname}
\tagline{tagline here}
\personalinfo{
Here is something \\
More text \\
Something.
}
\photo{2.8cm}{example-image-a}

\begin{document}

\makecvheader

\end{document}
```

Here I have used a package instead of a `.cls` file for convinience, but the result is the same as the `.cls` is based on `article.cls` with A4 paper and margin adjustments given in `mypackage`. I also included every package I import in the `.cls` as it is not many, and in case of some incompatability with provided solutions. Also, supposedly the `adjustbox` package can do `begin{minipage}{<width>, right}` which makes the minipage appear on the right. I tried this and using a if for the text environment, but it did not work.

I know the problem lies with `\ifdef{\@photodiameter}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em\relax}}{}%` and `\begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter}`. The textminipage is introduced first and is therefore put to the left of the photo minipage. I can't easaly swich the two because `\@photodiameter` is defined in the textminipage.

All other options (`nophoto`,`nophotocenter` and `normalphoto`) works fine.

---

---

Also: if it is relevant I use tabular and some commands inside `\personalinfo`. **If it is not relevnt to your solution, you can ignore this bit (but it is crutial that this works in your solution).** If you don't use the minipage environment in your solution, it must not break when using the following code. Here is an example:

```
\definecolor{soft_text}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}
\newcommand{\printinfo}[2]{\mbox{\textcolor{icons}{\normalfont #1}\hspace{1em}\textcolor{soft_text}{#2}\hspace{2em}}}

\newcommand{\emailsymbol}{\faAt}
\newcommand{\phonesymbol}{\faPhone}

\newcommand{\email}[1]{\printinfo{\emailsymbol}{\hspace{-0.2em}\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\phone}[1]{\printinfo{\phonesymbol}{\hspace{-0.1em}#1}}
```

Here is the personal info:

```
\personalinfo{%
%%   You can add your own with \printinfo{<symbol>}{<text>}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
  
  \email{your@email.com} &
  \phone{000-00-0000} %\tabularnewline
 
  \end{tabular}
}
```

It looks something like this (picture from the project and not the example above):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the photo inside of `\if@photoleft` on in front of the text (including the `\hfill`) and after the text for `\if@photoleft\else`. I also slimmed down your `\ifdef`-tests to just do `\ifdef\@photodiameter{}{\@nophototrue}`, and turned your text placement into a macro to make the width and scope of the `minipage` easier to grasp (the code should be easier to maintain this way).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

% No photo:
\newif\if@nophoto
\DeclareOption{nophoto}{\@nophototrue}
% No photo, centered text:
\newif\if@nophotocentered
\DeclareOption{nophotocenter}{\@nophotocenteredtrue \@nophototrue}
% Photo on the left side, text on the right:
\newif\if@photoleft
\DeclareOption{photoleft}{\@photolefttrue}
% Rectangular photo:
\newif\if@normalphoto
\DeclareOption{normalphoto}{\@normalphototrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{No option ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{geometry}          
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}       
\RequirePackage{xcolor}            
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}   
\RequirePackage{graphicx}        
\RequirePackage{dashrule}      
\RequirePackage{hyperref}         
\RequirePackage{tabularray}         
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}    
\geometry{%
        left=23mm,
        right=23mm, 
        bindingoffset=0mm, 
        top=20mm,
        bottom=20mm
    }

\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
\newcommand{\tagline}[1]{\def\@tagline{#1}}
\newcommand{\personalinfo}[1]{\def\@personalinfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\photo}[2]{\def\@photo{#2}\def\@photodiameter{#1}}

\newcommand*\cvheader@photo
  {%
    \if@nophoto
        % Don't include photo
    \else
        \begin{minipage}{\@photodiameter}%
        \if@normalphoto
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\@photo}%
        \else
          \tikz
            \path[fill overzoom image={\@photo}]circle[radius=0.5\linewidth];%
        \fi
        \end{minipage}%
    \fi%
  }

\newcommand*\cvheader@text[1]
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
      \if@nophotocentered
          \centering
      \fi
      \if@photoleft
          \raggedleft
      \fi
      {\Huge\bfseries\@name\par}%
      \medskip
      {\large\@tagline\par}%
      \medskip
      {\footnotesize\@personalinfo\par}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }

\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \ifdef\@photodiameter{}{\@nophototrue}%
    \if@photoleft
      \cvheader@photo
      \hfill
    \fi
    \if@nophoto
      \cvheader@text{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}%
    \else
      \cvheader@text{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@photodiameter-2em\relax}%
    \fi
    \if@photoleft\else
      \hfill
      \cvheader@photo
    \fi
    \par
  \endgroup
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\linia
  \medskip
}%
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[photoleft]{mypackage}

\name{Firstname Lastname}
\tagline{tagline here}
\personalinfo{
Here is something \\
More text \\
Something.
}
\photo{2.8cm}{example-image-a}

\begin{document}

\makecvheader

\end{document}
```